# Polymer braces with diagonal bonds

Tags: chemfig, braces, chemmacros

I searched the questions around here but I can`t find an answer to my problem. I´m trying to draw a polymer with `\chemfig` and everything works but the braces, specially the right one. 
I´m using this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
%\usepackage{math} 
\chemsetup{
  modules = {polymers}
}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{[:30]-[@{auf}](-[1](-[2,0.5]CH_2OH)-[0,2]O-[7])-[7](-[:30,0.5]OH)-[0,2](-[6,0.5]NH_2)-[1]-[:30]
O-[:-30](-[1](-[7,0.5]OH)-[0,2](-[2,0.5]NH_2)-[7][@{zu}])-[7](-[6,0.5]CH_2OH)-[0,2]O-[1]-[7]
}
\makepolymerdelims{30pt}{auf}{zu}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the correct polymer with just one wrong brace:
[image: polymer]

How can I fix this?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pair of unwanted brackets (you can see them if you comment out `\makepolymerdelims`) which stems from `[7][@{zu}]`. You must delete the `[@{zu}]` – it is at the wrong place anyway. Then change the *last* `[7]` in the whole formula into `[@{zu}7]`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
%\usepackage{math} 
\chemsetup{
  modules = {polymers}
}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{[:30]-[@{auf}](-[1](-[2,0.5]CH_2OH)-[0,2]O-[7])-[7](-[:30,0.5]OH)-[0,2](-[6,0.5]NH_2)-[1]-[:30]
O-[:-30](-[1](-[7,0.5]OH)-[0,2](-[2,0.5]NH_2)-[7])-[7](-[6,0.5]CH_2OH)-[0,2]O-[1]-[@{zu}7]
}
\makepolymerdelims{30pt}{auf}{zu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the sake of symmetry I'd also change the *beginning* `[:30]-[@{auf}]` into `-[@{auf}1]`:

[image]